# Decoding JSON using decoder

Tags: json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I'm following a tutorial on the new Codable protocol in Swift 4.  I'm retrieving JSON from iTunes.

I've setup my Data Model in a file (SearchResult.swift) that conforms to Codable:

```
class ResultArray: Codable {
    var resultCount = 0
    var results = [SearchResult]()
}

class SearchResult: Codable {
    var artistName = ""
    var trackName = ""

    var name: String {
        return trackName
    }
}
```

In my ViewController (SearchViewController.swift) I'm decoding the JSON.  What I don't understand is the reference to Self in ResultArray.self.  The result array object is not declared in the View Controller where I'm making the call.

```
func parse(data: Data) -> [SearchResult] {
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let result = try decoder.decode(ResultArray.self, from: data)
            return result.results
        } catch {
            print("JSON Error: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

Comment: The use of `self` is for getting the `Type` because the method (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode) is expecting a type to know to what transform the json (`data`). There a other sample where you do in that method `[SomeClass].self` to tell the decoder to transform into an array of that class.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode is  a *generic* function, taking a type (and data), and returning a value of that type.

Comment: Can you also post an example of the raw JSON